# Saving changes if adding to context

Tags: entity-framework-core

EF Core 2.2.x

The question Im trying to answer is if I can limit my call of SaveChanges to only once or do I need it each time I add an entity, since in the next lower level I need to query the DbContext to see if the item exists.

Am trying to "merge" some data between two sets of similar tables.  So in the process of adding records and drilling down the hierarchy, I have to first see if a record exists and if not, then add it.

```
/*
    List<StagedOrder> sorders;

    StagedOrder
    Id
    Number
    InsertDate
    Notes

    StagedOrderLine
    Id
    ItemNo
    Qty
    StagedOrderKey
*/    


   foreach( StagedOrder s in sorders) {

   // get order
   Order o = (from a in ctx.Orders where a.number = s.Number select a).FirstOrDefault();
   if(o == null) {
        o = new Order() {
            Number = s.Number,
            InsertDate = DateTime.Now,
            Notes = "imported order"
        };
        ctx.Orders.Add(o);
        // ctx.SaveChanges() ???
   }


   // get lines for orders
   OrderLines ol = (from a in ctx.DetailLines where a.OrderKey = o.Id select a).ToList();
   if(ol == null) {
        foreach(StagedOrderLine l in s.StagedOrderLines) {
            ol = new DetailLine() {ItemNo = l.ItemNo, Qty = l.Qty, OrderKey = l.Id}
            ctx.DetailLines.Add(ol);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
       }
   }

}

// can I limit my call to savechanges only once here?
// ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Also, should I create a new DetailLine using an Order.Id or an entity reference, eg.

```
ol = new DetailLine() {ItemNo = l.ItemNo, Qty = l.Qty, Order = o}
```

Comment: Yes, you can wait and call save changes once.

Comment: but if in the case of the Detail lines being searched using a OrderKey that isnt in the database yet,  when I add a new DetailLine I will need to provide a key value to the Order - or should I use an object reference?

Comment: if they are navigation properties then it should be OK.

Comment: Ok, see updates to post